# modify Proxy using powershell

Tags: powershell, proxy, registry

I have a problem related to the proxy. In fact, I am responsible for creating and configuring PCs for clients, and I have been working on this project for 2 months. Today, I need to write a PowerShell script that I should send to the clients to update their proxy settings. However, I realized that the PCs sent to the clients do not have a global proxy but rather a proxy per user, which was configured by modifying the registry settings for each user (meaning, by accessing each user's SID). The problem is that to perform the same manipulation again, all users of the PC must be signed in, otherwise I don't have access to the SID. And if I don't have access to the SID, I can't modify the users' proxy settings. So, I am unable to modify the proxies for all users, only for the user on which I run my script.
Is there a solution to bypass this and modify the proxy for each user, or perhaps create a global proxy that will override the user-specific proxies?
Thxxxx

I tried to search in the registries for a way to work around the issue, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: "The problem is that to perform the same manipulation again, all users of the PC must be signed in, otherwise I don't have access to the SID" - sounds like you might want to deploy it as a logon script, or perhaps a GPO or MDM policy depending on how they're managed

Comment: I am currently writing a script to run upon each user's login. I haven't found any other solutions at the moment; we'll see if this works.